# import python module using sys.path.append

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two python modules which I am trying to `import` using `sys.path.append` and `sys.path.insert`. Following is my code

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "/home/sam/pythonModules/module1")
sys.path.append("/home/sam/pythonModules/module2")

from lib.module1 import A
from lib.module2 import B
```

I have following folder structure

```
/home/sam/pythonModules/module1/lib/module1.py
/home/sam/pythonModules/module2/lib/module2.py
```

I am able to import lib.module1 but not lib.module2. If I do it like this

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "/home/sam/pythonModules/module2")
sys.path.append("/home/sam/pythonModules/module1")

from lib.module1 import A
from lib.module2 import B
```

then I am able to `import module2` but not `module1`.

*What can be the reason for the above importing errors?*

I tried `append` instead of `insert` in following manner but it's still doesn't work

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/sam/pythonModules/module1")
sys.path.append("/home/sam/pythonModules/module2")

from lib.module1 import A
from lib.module2 import B
```

Always only first module in `sys.path.append` is successfully imported.

But I make some changes to paths in `sys.path.append` in following manner then it works. Both the modules are imported successfully

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append("/home/sam/pythonModules/module1")
 sys.path.append("/home/sam/pythonModules/module2/lib")

 from lib.module1 import A
 from module2 import B
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use both `append` and `insert` on `sys.path`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do it that way.

Because of structure:

```
/home/sam/pythonModules/module1/lib/module1.py
/home/sam/pythonModules/module2/lib/module2.py
```

You can't put both:

- `/home/sam/pythonModules/module1` and
- `/home/sam/pythonModules/module2`

in `sys.path` and expect that Python will find:

- `module1` in `module1/lib` and
- `module2` in `module2/lib`

when you try import like:

```
from lib.module1 import A
from lib.module2 import B
```

If you put `/home/sam/pythonModules/module1` before `/home/sam/pythonModules/module2` in `sys.path` array, then `import lib.MODULE` will search for `MODULE` in `/home/sam/pythonModules/module1/lib`.

Since there is only `module1` and no `module2` in it, you get error.

What you can do is to put both

- `/home/sam/pythonModules/module1/lib/` and
- `/home/sam/pythonModules/module2/lib/`

in `sys.path` and expect Python to correctly import them with next lines:

```
from module1 import A
from module2 import B
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but what is the reason for this since `/home/sam/pythonModules/module1` and `/home/sam/pythonModules/module2` are both different path names.

Comment: Yes, but when Python searches for `lib` package, it finds it in first one of those paths and then uses that one for resolving subpackages/modules imports.

Answer (score 1):

Useless to use `sys.path.insert`, only if you want to prioritize your project before another in `PYTHONPATH`.

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/sam/pythonModules/module1")
sys.path.append("/home/sam/pythonModules/module2")

from lib.module1 import A 
from lib.module2 import B
```

Your projects `module1` / `module2` should be also structured as valid package, let see official guidelines: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

Comment: I have tried this but this doesn't work. Only first module is imported successfully.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` module in `/lib` package?

Comment: Yes I have empty `__init__.py` in `/lib` package