# Python ModuleNotFoundError - No module named 'pytorch_net'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import a file from a folder named pytorch_net from a folder named AI_physicist into a script named models.py. I have tried to change the folder locations of the files, get an **init**.py file into the main AI_physicist folder, and change the sys.path.append command to get only the folder with the files inside of it. I have also looked at other posts and have tried their solutions but to no avail.

Here are the posts that I have found and have tried:
[What does os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)) mean? python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005822/what-does-os-path-abspathos-path-joinos-path-dirname-file-os-path-pardir)

[import python module using sys.path.append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885445/import-python-module-using-sys-path-append)

file structure:

```
C:-----
  Users----
     trevo----
        Desktop----
          AI_physicist----
            pytorch_net----
            theory_learning----
```

Here is the error in its entirety:

```
No module named 'pytorch_net'
File "C:\Users\trevo\OneDrive\Desktop\AI_physicist\theory_learning\models.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pytorch_net.net import MLP
  File "C:\Users\trevo\OneDrive\Desktop\AI_physicist\theory_learning\theory_model.py", line 24, in <module>
    from AI_physicist.theory_learning.models import Loss_Fun_Cumu, get_Lagrangian_loss
```

And lastly here is the code that I am using:

models.py:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import grad
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname("__file__"), '..', '..'))
from AI_physicist.pytorch_net.net import MLP
from AI_physicist.pytorch_net.util import get_criterion, MAELoss, to_np_array, to_Variable, Loss_Fun
from AI_physicist.settings.global_param import PrecisionFloorLoss, Dt
from AI_physicist.theory_learning.util_theory import logplus
```

Any help on what I would be missing would be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: could you please provide your app folder structure?

Comment: Yep, I will make that edit right now.

Comment: in what folder did you store the folder **pytorch_net**?

Comment: I have edited it a second time to include pytorch_net

Comment: so you're importing using the command `from AI_physicist.pytorch_net.net import MLP` while error shows `from pytorch_net.net import MLP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `__init__.py` not `init.py` in that folder.

Alternatively:
`sys.path.append(f'{os.path.dirname(__file__)}\\folder_name')`
Please look on the difference between my and yours `sys.append`.
That should always work. Bare in mind these will work only if your script is in a subfolder of your main folder with main.py in.